# How to solve Flutter Pub get Failed error

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, gradle

**When I try to run Flutter Doctor -v, I get these**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Windows, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (2 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\CCS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin\java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-24)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.58.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.24.0

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.124
    • Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 91.0.864.67

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Which is fine except it shows Android Studio (not installed) which is installed in my PC
and when I run flutter create project_name I get

```
Creating project projectname...
  projectname\.gitignore (created)
  projectname\.idea\libraries\Dart_SDK.xml (created)
  projectname\.idea\libraries\KotlinJavaRuntime.xml (created)
  projectname\.idea\modules.xml (created)
  projectname\.idea\runConfigurations\main_dart.xml (created)
  projectname\.idea\workspace.xml (created)
  projectname\.metadata (created)
  projectname\android\app\build.gradle (created)
  projectname\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\example\projectname\MainActivity.kt (created)
  projectname\android\build.gradle (created)
  projectname\android\projectname_android.iml (created)
  projectname\android\.gitignore (created)
  projectname\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml (created)
  projectname\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml (created)
  projectname\android\app\src\main\res\drawable\launch_background.xml (created)
  projectname\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-v21\launch_background.xml (created)
  projectname\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
  projectname\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
  projectname\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
  projectname\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
  projectname\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
  projectname\android\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml (created)
  projectname\android\app\src\main\res\values-night\styles.xml (created)
  projectname\android\app\src\profile\AndroidManifest.xml (created)
  projectname\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties (created)
  projectname\android\gradle.properties (created)
  projectname\android\settings.gradle (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\AppDelegate.swift (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Runner-Bridging-Header.h (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\project.pbxproj (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\xcshareddata\xcschemes\Runner.xcscheme (created)
  projectname\ios\.gitignore (created)
  projectname\ios\Flutter\AppFrameworkInfo.plist (created)
  projectname\ios\Flutter\Debug.xcconfig (created)
  projectname\ios\Flutter\Release.xcconfig (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Contents.json (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-1024x1024@1x.png (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20@1x.png (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20@2x.png (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20@3x.png (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-29x29@1x.png (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-29x29@2x.png (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-29x29@3x.png (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-40x40@1x.png (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-40x40@2x.png (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-40x40@3x.png (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-60x60@2x.png (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-60x60@3x.png (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-76x76@1x.png (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-76x76@2x.png (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-83.5x83.5@2x.png (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\Contents.json (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\LaunchImage.png (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\LaunchImage@2x.png (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\LaunchImage@3x.png (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\README.md (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Base.lproj\LaunchScreen.storyboard (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Base.lproj\Main.storyboard (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner\Info.plist (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\project.xcworkspace\contents.xcworkspacedata (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\project.xcworkspace\xcshareddata\IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\project.xcworkspace\xcshareddata\WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner.xcworkspace\contents.xcworkspacedata (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner.xcworkspace\xcshareddata\IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist (created)
  projectname\ios\Runner.xcworkspace\xcshareddata\WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings (created)
  projectname\lib\main.dart (created)
  projectname\projectname.iml (created)
  projectname\pubspec.yaml (created)
  projectname\README.md (created)
  projectname\test\widget_test.dart (created)
  projectname\web\favicon.png (created)
  projectname\web\icons\Icon-192.png (created)
  projectname\web\icons\Icon-512.png (created)
  projectname\web\index.html (created)
  projectname\web\manifest.json (created)
Running "flutter pub get" in projectname...                     
pub get failed (1; no message)
```

So how can I fix the Problem **pub get failed(1; no message)**

I tried YouTube, GitHub issues and other websites hint to solve the problem but still nothing
I even tried some of the answers from other StackOverflow questions regarding the problem still nothing.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63112#issuecomment-691620053 ? PS: Why tagged Gradle?

Comment: Have you checked the path environment variable in your system is set correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, you can run "flutter config --android-studio-dir " to set the directory that Android Studio is installed to

Answer (score 0):

Try this its worked for me

flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\ProgramFiles\Android\Android Studio"

After run the code check flutter doctor